# Ktor KMP REQUEST failed with exception: kotlin.IllegalStateException: Invalid url

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I have a **KMP** project. I am implementing **Ktor** for network request. My android version is working completely fine. But when I run iOS version of the app, it gives below error:

```
REQUEST https://example.com/api/v1/history failed with exception: kotlin.IllegalStateException: Invalid url: https://example.com/api/v1/history
```

Does anyone know any reason for which this error might occur? I think there is no problem with the URL as it's working fine on Android version of the app. I also have tested the URL with other ways too.

My setup of HttpClient is as below

```
HttpClient {
        expectSuccess = true

        defaultRequest {
            host = "example.com/api/v1"
            url {
                protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
            }
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)

            // API Key
            header("X-API-KEY", BuildKonfig.API_KEY)
        }

        install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = 15_000
            connectTimeoutMillis = 15_000
        }

        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                prettyPrint = true
            })
        }

        install(Logging) {
            level = LogLevel.ALL
            logger = object : Logger {
                override fun log(message: String) {
                    Napier.i(tag = "ApiLog", message = message)
                }
            }
        }.also {
            Napier.base(DebugAntilog())
        }
    }
```

And in the calling side, I'm calling my API like below

```
client.get("history").body()
```

Comment: Can you share the code where the HttpClient is configured and the request is sent?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I have added the code in edited version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution. The problem was, I was settings `host = "example.com/api/v1"` in my HttpClient configuration, and was calling `client.get("history").body()` in my request side.
With below changing, my iOS version of the app finally worked

```
host = "example.com/api/v1"
```

to

```
host = "example.com"
```

and in request side

```
client.get("history").body()
```

to

```
client.get("api/v1/history").body()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the value passed for the `host` method, called in the `defaultRequest` block, is malformed. This method expects a value in the [Host header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) value format. If you intend to provide a complete default URL, then you can use the `url` method with a String parameter:

```
defaultRequest {
    url("https://example.com/api/v1/")
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)

    // API Key
    header("X-API-KEY", BuildKonfig.API_KEY)
}
```

The trailing slash is important because it signifies that the requested path will be **added** to the path of the default URL. Otherwise, the path will be replaced.